# How to get the index of a particular row using column values in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, numpy-slicing

So if I have the following array arr:

```
>>> arr
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]])
```

Now if I want to acquire the first row, I would do something like this :

```
>>> arr[0]
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

However, when I use np.where to locate a particular row, e.g.:

```
>>> np.where(arr == [0,1,2,3,4])
```

I get this output!

```
(array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3], dtype=int64), 
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=int64))
```

However, this is not what am after. I would like to get the row indices instead. e.g.:

```
(array([0, 3], dtype=int64)
```

Is there a way to achieve that? any advice is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to check if the rows are equal to a given array. In which case, you need `all`:

```
np.where((arr == [0,1,2,3,4]).all(1))
# (array([0, 3]),)
```

Comment: well done! thats exactly what I was after! I tried using all, yet I couldn't get the desired outcome!

Many thanks :)